# People Search Questions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, people-search

My people search for SharePoint 2013 will not work, no matter what I do.

Here is a list of things I have done to try to fix it:

1. Ensured that the User Profile Service and Search Service are in the Service Connections for the web applications where you I'm doing the search.
2. Configured a Content Source. Added the URL for any SharePoint Web Application, (using SSL, so I used the sps3s://url)
3. Configured Security on the User Profile Service application. Made sure the crawlers had permissions. The crawl is working because it is pulling in the appropriate number of profiles.
4. Did a full crawl on the Content Source containing my sps3 content source.

Here is one more piece of the puzzle:
When I go to User Profiles >Manage User Profiles I should be able to put 'mysiteurl' into the box and it should list all the profiles.

Except when I do it, I get no results.

Then I thought about how the profiles are listed in AD (the MILDOMAIN/User.Name) and I wondered if I just put MILDOMAIN into that box if it would list the profiles. It did. So it's not reading from the url, it's reading from Active Directory,

What happens when I do a search?
If I put in a name I get results back from documents uploaded and list items created, but if I use the drop down in the search box to select People or Conversations, I get an error `"Sorry, something went wrong /An unexpected error has occurred."`

Comment: That shows something is wrong with your search. There could be couple of reasons that its not showing the user profiles. First of all, please set the mysite host web application URL in sps3s://url and run a crawl again. Secondly, check in ULS logs and look for the correspondent GUID to get the exact error. That would help to understand the root cause of something went wrong error.

Comment: Can you explain the part about "Then I thought about how the profiles are listed in AD (the MILDOMAIN/User.Name) and I wondered if I just put MILDOMAIN into that box if it would list the profiles..." I don't understand but think this may be part of the issuse.

Comment: Here is the exception from the ULS Viewer <br /> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.PublishingPageStatusIndicator.AppendTranslationStatus(StringBuilder sb)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.PublishingPageStatusIndicator.RenderStatusString(Page page, String cssClass, String id, String& customStatusKey)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingPageStateControl.PopulateStatusMessages()    
 at

Comment: (cont.) <br /> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPPageStateControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.PublishingPageStateControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: All entries in AD are under a format that list their organization then their name, that way AD admins only have access to the ones under their domain as opposed to other domains in the military. So the way the account name is displayed is MILDOMAIN\User.Name. Does that help